# Connecting with remote SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Internet browsing has suggested me following connection string to access remote DB, attached to remote SQL server.

```
"Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

I want to access the DB over internet, not over LAN.
My question is about the IP address and port.

1)What IP address I should use instead of 190.190.200.100?  I mean how I can know what IP address my server has.
2) How to check the what port my server is using?  Is it always 1433?

Thanks

Comment: Two questions that can only be answered by whoever manages the server you are connecting to...

Comment: There must be some way to check the IP address and port of my SQL server, installed on my computer.

Comment: You need to connect to a public IP. You might want to encrypt the traffic in between because your password will be sent in clear text. You can look at this article : http://sqlblog.de/blog/2009/07/linked-sql-server-encrypted-connection/

Comment: Do I understand that the DB is on your machine and you want to access it from a remote location?

Comment: Is your local machine already accessible from the Internet?

Comment: You need to configure your router to port forward 1433 to your station then you will be able to connect to your public interface. Go check www.whatismyip.com from your SQL machine. Port is not always 1433. With SQL Express it is dynamically allocated.

Comment: Yes PollusB, you are right.  I want to access DB stored in my computer from a remote location.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx